# Como puedo ordenar de mayor a menor un array, que dentro de este tiene otro de tipo asociativo en php

Tags: php, array

El problema trata de que tengo ingresar nombre, id y edad, entonces después de leer los datos tengo que imprimirlos a modo de "tabla" de mayor a menor teniendo en cuenta la edad.
Sé que en php se usan sort, rsort y otra funciones para ordenamiento de arrays, pero no sé como hacerlo cuando se trata de un array dentro de otro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que el array que esta en la posición 1 pase a la posición 0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que espero que salga en este caso es que la fila que contiene "hola", "5", "87" quede en el lugar de la fila que contiene "AAA" es decir, que si la edad es mayor, entonces esta quede en la primera posición

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if ($_POST) {
        if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
            $_SESSION['personas'][]=["nombre" => $_POST['nombre'],
                                     "cedula" => $_POST['cedula'],
                                     "edad" =>    $_POST['edad']];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['eliminar'])){
            unset($_SESSION['personas'][$_POST['ind']]);
        }
        
        foreach($_SESSION['personas'] as $ind => $persona){
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" value = <?php echo $persona['nombre']?> name = "nombre" placeholder ="Nombre">
            <input type="text" value= <?php echo $persona['cedula']?> name="cedula" placeholder="Cedula">
            <input type="text" value= <?php echo $persona['edad']?> name="edad" placeholder="Edad">
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $ind?> name="ind">
            <button name="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
            
        </form>
        <?php
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_SESSION);
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: no te entiendo puedes agregar la estructura de lo que esperas que salga???

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 ya modifique la pregunta bro

Comment: usort($_SESSION['personas'],function($a,$b){
    return $a["edad"] <=> $b["edad"];
});

//prueba esto

Comment: @DavidGonzalo agregalo como respuesta para que te la marquen como respuesta... XD y yo yter ayudo con la redaccion de la misma...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 la verdad, no se como explicarlo, solo se que se hace asi y lo ultimo no lo entendi jejejej

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien dices se debería de usar `usort`, en donde `usort` lo que hace es ordenar un array, [aqui puedes encontrar la documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php).

Pero en este caso lo que deberías de hacer es buscar aplicarlo sobre la Edad de dentro de tu array y para eso se ocupa una funcion/callable:

```php
    usort(
        $_SESSION['personas'],
        function($a,$b) { 
            return $a["edad"] <=> $b["edad"];
    });
```

***Explicando que ocurre dentro de la funcion o callable:***

Lo que se espera es que el callable retorne un numero entero: `-1, 0 ,1` para asi saber si es menor, igual o mayor y determinar si el elemento se debe desplazar o mantener en la posicion del array... entonces por este motivo se usa el operador [`Nave espacial <=>`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php) que debe devolver uno de estos enteros a partir de `php 7`

Comment: que hace usort?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 dándole un array y una función ordena arrays

Comment: ok y que se supone que hace la funcion que esta dentro de la funcion osea como interactua esa funcion con el array???

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, siendo sincero la función que está dentro de la función no sé lo que hace, pero cunado aprendí usort en clase aprendí a hacerlo así

Comment: siendo aun más sincero que tu, creo que es lo mas importante en tu respuesta y que deberia quedar claro ... esperemos que unos de nuestros expertos en php nos pueda apoyar con una explicacion sobre el tema... y enrriquecer mas tu respuesta y nuestro conocimiento.

Comment: te juro que no respondi por que tenia la duda de que hacia lo de adentro del callable XD

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 por eso lo puse como un comentario y no como una respuesta… porque se como hacerlo pero no el porque

Comment: yo asumi que sabias enteramente que hacia todo XD

Comment: ya me dieron respuesta y actualice la tuya para que quede claro.